# Как определить производительность O()

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, c++, производительность

```
const int n = 21;
int x[n] = {1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 1, 2, 8, 0};
int k = 1;

for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if(x[i] != x[0])
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if(x[i] == x[j])
                x[j] = x[0];

        k++;
    }
}
cout << k << endl;
```

Задача: Дан массив с размером n. Найти количество различных чисел среди элементов этого массива.

Я написал алгоритм(знаю есть эффективнее не предлагать!). Как определить производительность этого алгоритма и вообще можете пожалуйста дать материал или сами объяснить как определять. Я считаю что у моего производительность меньше k^2 а как именно узнать O().

P.S. иногда еще пишут что производительность к примеру не O(log n) а C*log n где C - это константа этот момент можете тоже объяснить

Comment: Вот если есть задача и там n около 10^9 и ограничение по времени 2 секунды то какой эффективности должен быть алгоритм?

Comment: а кто его знает:) Но можно оценить. Пусть у нас процессор с 1Ггц, который делает 1 миллиард операций в секунду (да, это грубо, но для оценки более, чем достаточно).

Если алгоритм имеет линейную сложность, то получается, что на обработку одно элемента по 2 операции (кол-во операций в секунду * время / нужное кол-во операций). В случае квадратичной сложности значительно меньше.

2 операции на элемент - это уже мало. Поэтому скорее всего нужно либо алгоритм с линейной сложностью, либо научиться прореживать обработку. Либо искать алгоритм с константной скоростью.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определение эффективности алгоритма иногда очень нетривиальная задача. В первом томе Кнута описаны методы расчета. Но в большом случае для небольших алгоритмов можно оценить на глаз. В Вашем примере два цикла, вложенные один в другой. Поэтому скорее всего его сложность будет квадратичная O(n^2). Конечно, если все элементы массива будут одинаковые, то сложность его сразу стает линейной (так как внутренний цикл не исполняется). Но так как исходные данные не известные, то предполагают, что элементы достаточно разные.

По поводу константы "С". Даже если взять два алгоритма с линейной сложностью (с одним циклом), то можно догадаться, что внутри может быть тело с разной сложностью. И хотя оба с линейной сложностью, они будут исполнятся за разное время. Поэтому, может быть такая ситуация, что алгоритм с квадратичной сложностью до какого-то момента работает быстрее, чем алгоритм с линейной сложностью.

Comment: Ну да, это как например тело 1 алгоритма: n2 + 10n + 6, а второго: 1000000n + 5 при малых первый будет обгонять но при больших второй обгонит уже, значит С - это верхний предел вот этого n?

Comment: С - это некий коэффициент, который показывает как быстро исполняется алгоритм. В первом приближении можно считать, что он имеет размерность "время" и если для алгоритма известна оценка `C*O()`, то можно сказать, сколько оно время будет исполнятся.

Comment: тогда наверно C у каждого компьютера - свой? раз O() - это количество операций то C - Это за сколько выполняется одна операция?

Comment: конечно своя. Но разве это проблема?:)

Comment: нет, просто хотел уточнить правильно ли я вас понял, спасибо. А кроме Кнута можно еще гдето почитать про оценку? а то он мне сложным пока кажется для моего уровня?

Comment: Кнута рекомендуется читать так. Первое прочтение - как художественная литература. Если вывод какой-то формулы не понятен - пропускаем. Задачки просматриваем, если решить можем - решаем. Потом передышка. Потом читаем второй раз, на этот раз вдумчивее, прорабатываем непонятное, подгугливаем. И уже читая третий раз - решаем задачи. Но помним, что там есть задачи, которые и серьезные специалисты не сразу порешают (там в качестве шутки приводят теорему Ферма, которую только  недавно решили).

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, приму совет, но пока Кнута не трогая где почитать про оценку алгоримтов и как ее определять?

Comment: и мой ответ будет - начните с Кнута. Если человек учится читать и ему предлагают Букварь, то разве есть смысл отказаться? А ещё почитайте [здесь](http://blogerator.ru/page/zametki-ob-optimizacii-programm-2-big-o-notation-skorost-algoritmov-i-optimizacija-funkcij).

Comment: Например (из старого): 

Ахо А., Хопкрофт Дж., Ульман Дж. Построение и анализ вычислительных алгоритмов 

Э.Рейнгольд, Ю.Нивергельт, Н.Део Название: Комбинаторные алгоритмы. Теория и практика

Comment: [Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson — **Introduction To Algorithms**](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Introduction_To_Algorithms.html?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&redir_esc=y) (на мой взгляд, лучше начинать с нее, чем с Ахо и Ульмана).

Comment: Мне кажется ни в коем случае не надо начинать с Кнута. Вообще сейчас на coursera идут два курса по алгоритмам https://class.coursera.org/algs4partI-002/class/index и https://class.coursera.org/algo-003/class/index Там есть про асимптотическую сложность и есть рекомендованная литература. Кнута там кстати тоже не рекомендуют.

Answer (score 0):

Считать такты процессора.

```
inline _int64 HightTime(){
  _asm{
    rdtsc
  }
}
```

функция возвращает процессорное время

Comment: это и так понятно мне нужно именно ассимптотику, потому что когда обсуждают разные алгоритмы сортировки  и т.д. там говорят о производительности как O() а не 1500ms

Comment: видимо @perfect намекает на один с методов расчета - алгоритм прогоняется при разных `n`, измеряется время, а потом подбирается правильная функция.

Comment: один раз замеряешь перед алгоритмом затем второй после выполнения алгоритма. полученное время после выполнения алгоритма отнимаешь стартовое время и получаешь затраченное время на алгоритм то бишь узнаешь производительность алгоритма. чем меньше потраченное время тем быстрей алгоритм

Comment: вот дается мне задача и пореденное время на ее рещение я лучша прикину несколько способов решения и оценю на "скидку" их производительность, т.е. О(), чем реализую по отдельности каждый, при этом убирая баги, теряя время и потом только буду сранивать а какой же лучше, сами понимаете это никуда не годится

Comment: если алгоритм простой то можно и на вскидку. а вот если большой?

Comment: а большие нужно разбивать на маленькие кусочки и анализировать. И самое печальное, что это часто далеко не тривиальная задача. Кнут использует законы Кирхгофа и анализирует алгоритмы как электрические схемы.

Comment: Метод кстати вполне работоспособен. Можно накопить статистику и построить регрессионные зависимости времени выполнения от размерности.